# Determine Uninitialized Variable in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, initialization

I have this piece of code,

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *a)
{
    std::cout<<*a<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    foo(&i);
}
```

which is evident that an uninitialized variable is being used.

I have tried [/RTCu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx) as well as relied on [error C4700](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx), but for the above code, the compiler is not flagging this as an error.

I also tried running Code Analysis, bit it reported as the code fragment to have no issues.

So what is the reliable way to determine uninitialized variables in our source code?

I know `valgrind` does a wonderful JOB here but it is not an option for me as I have lots of calls to Windows APIs and MFC.

Comment: It is "evident" to you but not to the compiler: you pass the variable to a (non-inline) function through a pointer indirection (note that making the function inline and enabling inlining does trigger a warning with gcc). Now, not an answer but why defining uninitialized variables in the first place? A simple way to avoid problems is to always initialize a variable when defining it (which implies not defining it until you can initialize it).

Comment: @gx_: I am not defining uninitialized variables but sanitizing the code base having one for possible issues. Also I disagree `It is "evident" to you but not to the compiler`. To prove my point I have to run Valgrind over the above code base and determine its response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (I had suspected the "not my code" but it costs nothing to precise it). But I maintain, it is obviously _not_ evident for the compiler; if it were it would warn on it (make `foo` inline and _then_ it becomes evident to the compiler). Also valgrind is not a compiler nor a static analysis tool but a _dynamic_ checker.

Comment: The pointer is valid so that's where /RTCu ends.  You rely on /RTCs in a case like this, the value -858993460 stands out noticeably.

Comment: What do you have the project warnings level set to?  Under project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Warning Level.  Try setting it to Level 4 or All and recompile.  There are some cases where the compiler will catch uninitialized variables being used, but not all of them.

Comment: _"So what is the reliable way to determine uninitialized variables in our source code?"_ One cannot exist in general. It is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way for a compiler determine all cases of uninitialized variables. Valgrind (and other tools like it) are not compilers, but dynamic analysis tools, like user *gx* above said. There are also static analysis tools that can detect many cases of use of unitialized variables. But generally compilers are no match for those specialized tools.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the static analysis portion: As of VS2013, I would not depend on the default analyzers to catch too much, if you have access to another static analysis tool (although it is good to use VS to catch what others might miss). Although it is likely not the case here, note that static analyzers may disregard patterns that they see in many places or that have been overridden by other developers as the acceptable norm. I would be surprised if Coverity did not report this case, though (sorry, don't have it installed ATM for testing). If it did ignore it, an explanation might be that it was considered a possible shared memory address.

Comment: Coverity (at least on my setup) did not catch this either. Apparently the function-depth of the analysis is very restricted. In other cases of uninitialized variables, the compile process usually catches it, so maybe they are relying on that. Interesting case, wouldn't have guessed.